# How to execute in other directory?

Tags: c, bash, executable

I have three directories:

1. `/home/Desktop/1`
2. `/home/Desktop/2`
3. `/home/Desktop/3`

In the directories 1 and 2 are executable C programs, which can be executed in the terminal like this `./tst1` or `./tst2`.

In the directory 3 I have a bash script, which executes a C program tst3.c from the same directory.

I want to execute these C programs from directories 1 and 2 using my bash script in the directory 3 like this

```
#!/bin/bash

sudo ./tst3
sleep 1
sudo ./tst1 # from directory 1
sleep 2    
sudo ./tst2 # from directory 2
```

Any ideas?

Comment: Why not `sudo /home/Desktop/1/tst1`?

Comment: Your question is ambiguous. When you say you want to execute "in other directory", do you mean the executable is in another directory, you want the current working directory to be another directory, both, or something else?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have multiple options, including at least:

1. Set PATH to include the directories where your commands are found:

   ```
   #!/bin/bash
   export PATH="$PATH:/home/Desktop/1:/home/Desktop/2:/home/Desktop/3"
   sudo tst3 # from directory 3
   sleep 1
   sudo tst1 # from directory 1
   sleep 2    
   sudo tst2 # from directory 2
   ```
2. Use absolute paths to the commands:

   ```
   #!/bin/bash
   sudo /home/Desktop/3/tst3 # from directory 3
   sleep 1
   sudo /home/Desktop/1/tst1 # from directory 1
   sleep 2    
   sudo /home/Desktop/2/tst2 # from directory 2
   ```
3. Use relative paths to the commands:

   ```
   #!/bin/bash
   sudo ../3/tst3 # from directory 3
   sleep 1
   sudo ../1/tst1 # from directory 1
   sleep 2    
   sudo ../2/tst2 # from directory 2
   ```

These treat the directories symmetrically.  Another alternative is to place the commands in a directory already on your PATH (like `$HOME/bin`, perhaps), and then run them without any path.  This is what I'd normally do — ensure the commands to be run are in a directory on my PATH.

Comment: You could also do what [ikegami](https://stackoverflow.com/users/589924/ikegami) suggests in this [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/43595929/): change directory to where the commands are stored so that you can use the `sudo ./tstN` notation for each command.

Comment: The third one will fail if the CWD isn't `/home/Desktop/3` (but then again, so would the OP's).

Comment: @ikegami: that's  sort of true, but it makes no assumption that the script in the question didn't make.  That is, the script in the question would fail if the current directory is not `/home/Desktop/3`.  Formally, I think the third sequence in my answer would only fail if the current directory is not either one of the 3 named directories or not a directory at the same level as those directories (so it would work if the current directory was `/home/Desktop/4`, but not if it was `/home/Desktop` or `/home/Desktop/3/sub-directory`) — or the usual reasons like files have been removed.

Comment: Re "*it makes no assumption that the script in the question didn't make*", Yes, I pointed that out. But, seeing as you recommended two ways of lanching programs that would break #3 if used to launch the script, I felt it was worth mentioning. /// Re "*Formally, ...*", Well yeah. I "simplified" :)

Comment: I didn't see that you'd edited in that comment when I started responding...

Answer (score 2):

If you are simply trying to locate the scripts:

```
#!/bin/bash
base_dir="$( dirname "$( readlink -e "$0" )" )"/..

sudo "$base_dir/3/tst3"
sleep 1
sudo "$base_dir/1/tst1"
sleep 2    
sudo "$base_dir/2/tst2"
```

or

```
#!/bin/bash
cd "$( dirname "$( readlink -e "$0" )" )"/..

sudo 3/tst3
sleep 1
sudo 1/tst1
sleep 2    
sudo 2/tst2
```

If you want the CWD to be changed the directory of each executable before executing it:

```
#!/bin/bash
cd "$( dirname "$( readlink -e "$0" )" )"
sudo ./tst3

cd ../1
sleep 1
sudo ./tst1

cd ../2
sleep 2    
sudo ./tst2
```

These scripts will work properly even if its launched from a directory other than the directory it's found in. They will even work if they are launched via a symlink!